# Kinesis Video Stream C++ Error

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Anybody else seen this error with the kinesis video cpp Gstreamer example?

I’ve tried lots of different avenues but can’t seem to get a working fix!

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
DEBUG - Stream is ready
Error received from element source-actual-src-avfvide: Internal data stream error.
Debugging information: gstbasesrc.c(2939): void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *) (): /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstAutoVideoSrc:source/GstAVFVideoSrc:source-actual-src-avfvide:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
INFO - Freeing Kinesis Video Stream test

freeKinesisVideoStream(): Freeing Kinesis Video stream.DEBUG - streamDataAvailableHandler invoked
DEBUG - streamClosedHandler invoked

freeKinesisVideoClient(): Freeing Kinesis Video Client
commonHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): Heap is initialized
commonHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): Heap limit: 
536870912
commonHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): Heap size: 
0
commonHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): Number of allocations: 
0
aivHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): Allocated blocks pointer: 
0x0
aivHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): *******************************************
aivHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): *******************************************
aivHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): Free blocks pointer: 
0x107949000
aivHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): *******************************************
aivHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): Block:
0x107949000 size:
536870872
aivHeapDebugCheckAllocator(): *******************************************
heapRelease(): Freeing native heap.INFO - Curl shutdown
```

Answer (score 1):

looking at the source element it looks like you are on a mac. you can try export GST_DEBUG=4 before you start running the sdk and look for lines that contains `creating caps event`. On the same line you should see something like `width=(int)1280, height=(int)720` which is the resolution of the video stream being negotiated in the pipeline. Look for the first occurrence of such width and height info in the debug message. They look something like:

```
avfvideosrc avfvideosrc.m:906:-[GstAVFVideoSrcImpl setCaps:]_block_invoke:<source-actual-src-avfvide> width: 1280 height: 720 format: UYVY
```

This is the resolution that the camera supports. If this resolution does not agree with the resolution set in downstream elements then you will have the `not-negotiated` error. In your case it's likely that the downstream element didn't set a resolution of 720p. You can fix this by changing line 347, 348, 367, 368 in kinesis_video_gstreamer_sample_app.cpp to

```
"width", GST_TYPE_INT_RANGE, 1280, 1920,
"height", GST_TYPE_INT_RANGE, 720, 1080,
```

The changed value represents the lower bounds for resolution negotiation.